# FTP Image Slider

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a slider that i fill in an ftp link address with username and password then it plays the images in that folder location in the server?

I have tried wow slider but this slider only allows one to publish to an FTP server and not the other way round.

I seem not to find it. This is what i need:

1. I have my android app upload images to my server via ftp to a folder called "EVENTS"
2. Now i need to be able to play all images in the folder "EVENTS" on my website.

How do i do this?

Comment: You should use PHP for something like this. Take a look at this: http://www.ubergallery.net/

Comment: I am making my website in C#. Could you know a way around it in Asp.Net?

Answer (score 0):

If you have basic knowledge of html5 css and jquery then you should use http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/. 
If i understand, I think there is no need to use ftp if you are going to use this slider for website. Make sure your folder images must be accessible via web url.